# Using a third party script button, trigges when clicking other buttons on page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I am using aspx, Visual Studio.net, and VB.

I am trying to integrate Stripe for the payment of my site users. I have added the Stripe script inside the body.

This is supposed to open a payment form whenever the Pay button is clicked. This works fine, but my problem is it triggers and opens the payment form whenever I press any other buttons on my page.

Here is my code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div id="paymentButton" runat="server">
                            <script
                                src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
                                data-key="My_Key"
                                data-name="My Name"
                                data-description="Subscription"
                                data-locale="auto"
                                data-currency="aud">
                            </script>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnNextPage" runat="server" Text="Next Page" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to go to other pages, when clicking in the btnNextPage. But when I click on btnNextPage button, I also opens the payment form.

Would you please advise?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, ASP.NET buttons (e.g. `<asp:Button>`, `<asp:LinkButton>`, etc.) trigger form postback when clicked, `<asp:HyperLink>` is more suitable for navigation.

If you do want to use button for navigation, however, you could use html `<button>` and do navigation in its `onClick` event like

```
<button onclick="window.location.href='nextPage.aspx';return false">Next Page</button>
```